# how to initialize firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

hi need to get data from firestore  inside a cloud function, to inizialize firebase I have a file firebase.ts:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
  privateKey: functions.config().private.key.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
  projectId: functions.config().project.id,
  clientEmail: functions.config().client.email,
}),
databaseURL: `https://${functions.config().project.id}.firebaseio.com`,
});

  const app = initializeApp({
  appId:functions.config().app.id

})
const db = getFirestore();
const realtime = admin.database();
export {admin, db, realtime};
```

then I  use in my index.ts

```
const ref = doc(db, "users", uid);
```

my problem is that visual studio code reports me this error, for db inside doc:

```
no overload matches this calls
 Argument of type 'Firestore' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference<unknown, DocumentData>'.
  Type 'Firestore' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentReference<unknown, DocumentData>': converter, type, firestore, id, and 3 more.
```

I followed the official  docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data and https://blog.logrocket.com/building-rest-api-firebase-cloud-functions-typescript-firestore/

but nothing works, maybe some problems of configuration  I do not know, thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can't use firebase-admin in web client code at all.  It's not supported for use in browsers - it works on nodejs only.  You only use it for backend code, such as Cloud Functions.  Remove firebase-admin from your angular project and use the client APIs only.  If you're trying to invoke an HTTP type cloud function from your frontend, then all you need to do is make a normal HTTP request to the endpoint it was assigned after you deployed it.

Similarly, the Firebase web client SDKs are not generally for use with backend code.  Use firebase-admin only for that.  The code you have now is trying to use them both together.  That will never work.  They are not compatible with each other and have completely different APIs. If you are writing Cloud Function code, remove the client SDK (firebase/app) and use firebase-admin only.  You can init firebase-admin in Cloud Functions as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). The only code you need is:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
initializeApp()
```